# Setup File with Start up Folder

Tags: c#, winforms

I Have created a application, and i want to create a set up file, where the application should run automatically like when we move it to start up folder. but here i want to keep it when it will install the application.

and second thing, I want to implement also when my application will close, but that application should not quit, it will run like any anti virus software, skypee, etc. and we can maximize it from show hidden icons

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a [Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

The service will run at all times even when no-one is logged in.

A WinForms application could be added to the system tray [How to make a Windows Forms .NET application display as tray icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158895/how-to-make-a-windows-forms-net-application-display-as-tray-icon) and it could communicat with the service to find out its status or to configure it.