# How to send toast notifications with closed WinForms C# App?

Tags: c#, winforms

Good day, I have a windows forms application, it's an alarm application, in the form 1 (main form) there are 2 datetimepickers, and 2 button.
The datetimepicker 1, it's linked with button 1, when you press button 1, it should send a notification to you (with the notification control), and the other datetimepicker and button 2, are for the same, just a second alarm.

That's all I've tried and all I know, the problem now is that I Can't send the notifications with the app closed, that basically is the application purpose.
The only thing that I guess it could be, it's to create another thread or something similar but that works like a normal task, In background, like the ones that you could cancel in the task manager.

This is the Main Form:

[image: Main Form]

Comment: If you want to be able to close (not minimise) your application but still have it run, look into Windows services or Windows scheduled tasks.

Comment: The app can not do anything while it is closed. So that leaves you with two ways: 1. Let somebody else make the notifications. The Task Sheduler is a possible way. 2. Never (really) close. Avoid Services as they can not interact with the Desktop easily. Much more common is to simply have it work as a Tray Icon (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158895/how-to-make-a-windows-forms-net-application-display-as-tray-icon). You still need to start it with every user, and for that I would look at the Sheduler. It has options for just that kind auf Autostart,